# Is it possible to refer to the type of the object in a TypeScript interface with an array of objects in it?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an interface like the following:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  prop1: {
    nestedProp1: number;
    nestedProp2: string;
  }[];
};
```

I can refer to the `prop1` array type itself with `MyInterface['prop1']`, but is there a proper way to refer to the type of the object in the array, which would end up being:

```
{
  nestedProp1: number;
  nestedProp2: string;
}
```

Comment: Same logic: `MyInterface['prop1'][0]` (or `[number]`).

Comment: may be you are talking about typeof ?
`const a : MyInterface = {prop1 : [{nestedProp1 : 1, nestedProp2:"dummy"}]};
type MyInterfaceUnderlyingType = typeof a.prop1[0];`

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER that works too, but I'd like to define it in an interface. I've decided to go with @jonrsharpe 's answer of `MyInterface['prop1'][number]` because it feels more principled than tacking a `[0]` on the end.